# Test my WordPress Plugin standard or not

Tags: plugins

I developed a plugin. Now i want to submit it wordpress.org. but i'm little bit confused my code standard or not. My plugin working properly. I think it's my have some quality and security issue. 
Now My question is that there is available any kind of tool where i can check my plugin vulnerability or quality.

Answer (score 1):

There’s an official guideline https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/ but no automatic test tool for code quality and security.
The plugin team will check your plugin and also gives you some recommendations if something doesn’t fit their standards. 
One of my plugins had to be changed to be approved.
It’s a friendly team, they won’t reject your plugin without detailed instructions how to get it approved.
You can also post a link to your plugin here and I can have a quick look if you like.